doc.generate_pdf() is not working in google colab
I want to read image from google drive and add it to document and save it as pdf.
This is my code:
# Create a new LaTeX document
doc = Document(documentclass='article')

# Add a section
with doc.create(Section('Adding an Image Example')):
    doc.append('This is an example of how to add an image to a LaTeX document using Python.')

# Specify the path to the folder containing the images
folder_path = '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/SSY_SEVA_24/SSY_try (File responses)/Upload (File responses)'

for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
        
        # Check if the file is an image
        if file_name.endswith('.jpg') or file_name.endswith('.jpeg'):
          print(file_name)
          # Add the image
          with doc.create(Figure(position='h!')) as fig:
              fig.add_image(file_name, width=NoEscape(r'0.8\textwidth'))
              fig.add_caption('Example Image')


doc.generate_pdf('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/SSY_try (File responses)/pdf_latex', clean_tex=False)

I'm getting this error:

CalledProcessError: Command '['pdflatex', '--interaction=nonstopmode', '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/SSY_try (File responses)/pdf_latex.tex']' returned non-zero exit status 1

I'm not sure how exactly the problem can be solved.

Check this out: https://github.com/JelteF/PyLaTeX/issues/261
